# Uso de typedef y funciones

Tags: c++

El objetivo del programa es elegir un numero, 1 piedra, 2 papel y 3 tijera. 
Inicialmente el programa almacena un numero en el subprograma tElemento eleccionHumano() y luego convierte ese valor entero en piedra, papel o tijera en el subprograma string elementoAstring().

No obstante estaré haciendo mal uso de estas funciones.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
#include<windows.h>
using namespace std;


typedef enum {Piedra,Papel,Tijera} tElemento;


tElemento eleccionHumano();
string elementoAstring(tElemento elemento);



int main()
{
 tElemento eleccionHumano();
 string  elementoAstring(tElemento elemento);
}


tElemento eleccionHumano()
{
  tElemento eleccion;
  int numero;
  cout <<endl<<"Elige un elemento <1-piedra, 2-papel, 3-tijera>: ";
  cin >> numero;
  eleccion= tElemento(numero);
}

string elementoAstring(tElemento elemento)
{
 string ElementoHumano;
 if (elemento == 1)
{
    ElementoHumano = "Piedra";
}
else if (elemento == 2)
{
    ElementoHumano = "Papel";
}else if (elemento ==3)
{
    ElementoHumano = "Tijera";
}
cout << "Ha elegido " << ElementoHumano;
}
```

Comment: El programa en si se abre, lo que pasa que no ejecuta nada. Será que no estoy llamando correctamente a la función tElemento eleccionHumano()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C++ no es C y esto es aplicable a unas cuantas características:

**enumerados**

No es necesario usar `typedef`... no ensuciemos el código de forma gratuita:

```
enum tElemento {Piedra,Papel,Tijera}; // C++
```

**conversiones**

C++ dispone de 4 tipos de conversiones diferentes. La gran ventaja de estas conversiones es que son bastante más seguras que las conversiones de C y además pueden localizarse fácilmente en el texto usando las herramientas de búsqueda:

```
eleccion= tElemento(numero);               // C
eleccion = static_cast<tElemento>(numero); // C++
```

**Variables al inicio**

Ni en C (al menos desde el estándar C99 (que data de 1999 OJO!!!) ni en C++ (desde tiempos inmemoriales) es necesario declarar las variables al inicio de la función.

Las variables se pueden declarar en el momento que más convenga, y lo conveniente es acortar su vida lo máximo posible...

```
tElemento eleccionHumano()
{
  // tElemento eleccion; <--- MAL
  int numero;
  cout <<endl<<"Elige un elemento <1-piedra, 2-papel, 3-tijera>: ";
  cin >> numero;
  //                  vvvvvvvvvvv Esto ya lo hemos explicado en el punto anterior
  tElemento eleccion= static_cast<tElemento>(numero);
  // ^^^^^^ Mejor aqui
}
```

Y ahora otros detalles aplicables tanto a C como a C++:

**Retornos**

Si una función tiene un tipo de retorno tiene que usar **necesariamente** al menos un `return`. Piensa que la función va a devolver un valor sí o sí y si no lo eliges tú el programa lo hará por ti... ¿Crees que va a acertar y va a devolver lo que tu esperas? Se aceptan apuestas...

```
tElemento eleccionHumano()
{
  int numero;
  cout <<endl<<"Elige un elemento <1-piedra, 2-papel, 3-tijera>: ";
  cin >> numero;
  tElemento  eleccion = static_cast<tElemento>(numero);

  return eleccion; // <<--- FALTABA return
}

string elementoAstring(tElemento elemento)
{
  string ElementoHumano;
  if (elemento == 1)
  {
    ElementoHumano = "Piedra";
  }
  else if (elemento == 2)
  {
    ElementoHumano = "Papel";
  }else if (elemento ==3)
  {
    ElementoHumano = "Tijera";
  }
  cout << "Ha elegido " << ElementoHumano;

  return ElementoHumano; // <<--- FALTABA return
}
```

**Ojo con las declaraciones**

```
int main()
{
  tElemento eleccionHumano();
  string  elementoAstring(tElemento elemento); 
}
```

En esas pocas líneas del main...

- `tElemento eleccionHumano();` es una declaración de una función llamada `eleccionHumano` que no recibe parámetros y que devuelve un objeto de tipo `tElemento`.
- `string  elementoAstring(tElemento elemento);` es otra declaración de otra función...

prueba con esto:

```
int main()
{
  tElemento elemento = eleccionHumano();
  elementoAstring(elemento); 
}
```

Comment: Mas profesional,clara y útil no podría ser la respuesta. Gracias por corregir todos lo fallos. Un saludo