# Puntero dinámico de array de estructuras

Tags: c++, punteros

El objetivo es crear un puntero que apunte a un array de estructuras para una vez finalizado el programa liberar memoria.

Este es mi código:

```
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

typedef struct
{
    string nombre;
    int puntuacion;
}tFicha;


typedef struct
{
    int cont;
    tFicha *ficha;
}tPuntuaciones;


int main()
{
    tPuntuaciones puntos;
    puntos.ficha = new tFicha[];
}
```

En el código:

> typedef struct {
>       int cont;
>       tFicha *ficha; }tPuntuaciones;

Se crea un puntero que apunta a la estructura directamente ¿Es esto correcto, no debería apuntar al array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> En el código:
>
> > ```
> > typedef struct { int cont; tFicha *ficha; }tPuntuaciones;
> > ```
>
> Se crea un puntero que apunta a la estructura directamente.

No es cierto.

---

En ese código no creas nada, declaras un alias para la estructura `{ int cont; tFicha *ficha; }` llamado `tPuntuaciones`. Este alias es completamente innecesario en C++ como ya te señaló [eferion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/463/eferion) en (al menos) [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/134298/2742) y [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/114943/2742) respuesta. Tu estructura podría quedar así:

```
struct tPuntuaciones { int cont; tFicha *ficha; };
```

También podrías aprovechar para inicializar las variables miembro:

```
struct tPuntuaciones { int cont = 0; tFicha *ficha = nullptr; };
```

Y ya que estamos en C++ ¿por qué no usar constructores?:

```
struct tPuntuaciones
{
    tPuntuaciones(int elementos) :
        cont{elementos},
        ficha{new tFicha[cont]}
    {}

private:
    int cont = 0;
    tFicha *ficha = nullptr;
};
```

Es en el constructor donde haces que apunte al array.

Dado que manejas memoria internamente, tendrás que vigilar en las copias o movimientos... o mejor aún: olvidate de manejar memoria a mano y usa un `std::vector`:

```
struct tPuntuaciones
{
private:
    std::vector<tFicha> ficha{};
};
```